# Physics going crazy for rigid body objects. They jump out of the jar

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

Because I can't figure this out right now, I am going to bruit force position my paint brushes in the jar. But what I am trying to do is stand some paint brushes in a jar just a bit off the bottom and let the rigid body physics decide how they should fall and settle into the jar.

What is happening is the brushes go crazy and bounce out of the jar. I turned off the physics for all of the brushes except for one to see what is happening and it appears as if it is gaining energy until if flies out of the jar and lands on the ground, then it settles down but keeps moving forever until I run out of animation frames.

I have tried tweaking various settings and it just gets more crazy as I tweak things. Selecting the mesh for the shape is one of the worst. The brush instantly flies off into space never to be seen again by frame 6 or 7. Convex Hull, Cylinder and Capsule all do pretty good but they still gain energy until they jump out of the jar.

The origin is at the center of mass. I have tried moving it up and down and that only makes things worse.

The brush is an active rigid body. The jar and floor are passive rigid bodies.

Any advice on how to get them to simply drop into the jar and settle would be appreciated. Here are some screen shots showing what is going on. Frames 1, 19, 59 and 80...

[image: 01]

[image: 19]

[image: 59]

[image]

Comment: If u provide blend file, I will check it out

Comment: 9 times out of 10 it's because of the options for the container object.  Try changing convex hull to mesh and see if that works.

Comment: When this happens to me it's usually the mass vs scale -- I can see from your screenshots that both your scale and the paintbrush's mass are close to real-world accurate, but that doesn't mean much if you're not getting the effect you want.  First, I'd recommend you apply your scale on the paintbrush (Ctrl-A > Scale), if that doesn't help then try with decreased / increased mass in Rigid Body > Settings

Comment: I have no idea how to directly attach a blend file to this question, but you can pull it from my cloud server here: https://cloud.schworak.com/index.php/s/bmazLWBtsJSCaSf